# VBA to jump to certain cell after changing contents of one

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a spreadsheet that I want to force people to input certain information. Is there anyway of forcing people when changing the contents of a cell that once return or tab is entered that it jumps to another cell.

For Instance:

```
CELL C2 (Date)         01/01/2001
CELL C4 (EMPTY)        JUMP HERE
```

So above I want someone to enter a date in `C1` and when they change this is jumps to `C3`.

Kris

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640) will get you started

Comment: If you protect the sheet and only leave the cells you want to be changed unlocked then tab will move to the next unlocked cell, provided you tick the correct restrictions for locked cells

Answer (score -2):

The selection of a specific cell in the first sheet:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Select
```

You can use name of the sheet as a string instead of 1 in sheets(1)